# No error or output when C++ executable is run from Java

Tags: java, c++, executable

I am trying to run a c++ executable from my Java web application. When I go the relevant page it executes the commands and runs the executable but does not produce any output.

Here is my code:

```
URL createWav = QRcodeController.class.getClassLoader().getResource("createWav");
log.info("The path of the c++ executable obtained: "+ createWav.getPath());
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 " + createWav.getPath());
p1.waitFor();
int exitVal=1;
try {
        Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(createWav.getPath(), args);
        exitVal = p2.waitFor();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    log.error(e.getStackTrace());
}
if(exitVal == 1)
    throw new Exception("Error in c++ program");
```

It does not throw any error so the c++ program runs fine but it does not produce the file it is supposed to. When I run the same command from the command line in the same machine it works perfectly producing the required file. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Could you retry this with a hard coded path?  It might be that the file is being created by the Java program but in a different place.

Comment: It was not able to run the program so that is why I could not find the file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ program is writing its output to a pipe, not the standard output of the Java program. Use [Process.getOutputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29) to access that stream or, with Java 1.7, employ a `ProcessBuilder` where you can use [redirectOutput](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput%28java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect%29) like this:

```
pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
```

In case your C++ program *might* write things to its standard error stream, you should probably deal with that in the same way.

Also note that leaving either of these streams connected to a pipe and *not* reading from that pipe might cause your application to block on output if the buffer associated with the pipe becomes full. To simply ignore output, you'd have to explicitely redirect it to `/dev/null`. That's not your aim just now, but it might be in a different situation.

Answer (score 2):

Get the output stream and the error stream from the [process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) to see what happens.

Now you're working blindly.

Comment: Thanks I am able to see the output now and currently onto debugging it. Thanks for the help.